# Java- Convert String Value to Integer

Tags: java, json

I am getting the json data from an API as String but I want to store it in DB and use it as integer. For example I am getting A=15K or 15M but I want 15000.

Here is my class

```
public class JsonRestApi {
    public JsonRestApi() {
        try {
            String Response = "{\"Youtube Data\":{\"Views\":\"15K\"}}";

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try {
                Object obj = parser.parse(Response);

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                JSONObject jsonObject3  = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Youtube Data");

                String yviews = (String)jsonObject3.get("Views");
                System.out.println(yviews);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Output- 15K

**But I want output as 15000**.
However I do not want to change my Json data.
How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Why 15000? 10K is 10000?!

Comment: see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77697/convert-a-formatted-file-size-to-bytes

Comment: Try to get last character and multiply value.

Comment: `s = s.replaceFirst("(?i)\\s*K$", "000").replaceFirst("(?i)\\s*M$", "000000").replaceFirst("(?i)\\s*G$", "000000000")`

Comment: @Joop Suppose if I have views = 15.4K value then according to your code it would print 15.4000 but what i want is 15400

Comment: @Sarthak of course, so we have to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace K, M etc. with the appropriate number of zeroes.

```
String yviews = (String)jsonObject3.get("Views");
yviews = yviews.replace( "K", "000").replace( "M", "000000");
System.out.println(yviews);
```

Edit: If your number of views can have floating point numbers, you can use the following code:

```
String[][] conversionMatrix = {{"K", "1000"}, {"M", "1000000"}, {"B", "1000000000"}};

for( int i = 0; i < conversionMatrix.length; i++)
{
    if( yviews.endsWith( conversionMatrix[i][0]))
    {
        BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal( yviews.substring( 0, 
                                            yviews.indexOf( conversionMatrix[i][0])));
        temp = temp.multiply( new BigDecimal( conversionMatrix[i][1]));
        yviews = temp.toBigInteger().toString();
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println( yviews);
```

Comment: Suppose if I have views = 15.4K value then according to your code it would print 15.4000 but what i want is 15400

Comment: If your views can have floating point numbers, you need a different approach, see the edit.